# problems in launching docker from aws batch executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, aws-batch

I have a docker image Im setting up like this

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libssl-dev python3.7-dev curl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY mypackage/


ENV PATH /root/.poetry/bin:${PATH}

RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python && \
    cd mypackage && \
    poetry install && \
    mkdir /workingdir

WORKDIR /mypackge

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]
```

and I can enter it locally and run poetry run mypackage run

I can also use docker image exec poetry run mypackage run

and it works

Im deploying to AWS ECR and running the container from AWS batch.

command I am firing atm is, Ive tried with and without the bash -c

```
"command": ["bash", "-c", "poetry", "run", "mypackage", "run"],
```

but I always fail to find poetry, I put a simple echo or something in and container works.
Its like it doesnt have access to the $PATH env var when launching from aws batch

cloudwatch logs show

```
run: poetry: command not found
```

and in step Ive had

```
container process caused \"exec: \\\"poetry\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown",
```

so it seems it doesn see the PATH env var in the container when running from AWS batch but it does locally using exec.

how can I make this work from AWS batch rather than just locally?